# Why is the redux store state showing `false` within render(), even though the default state is `true`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following code. It is using an older version of React, but why does the redux store state, `!!this.state.checked`, show up as `false` within `render()`... Despite the `defaultState` being `true`?

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';



const defaultState = { checked: true };
const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE':
      return { ...state, checked: !state.checked };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const store = createStore(reducer);



class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  // deprecated from react version 17
  // but this is using react version 15 only
  componentWillMount() {
    store.subscribe(() => this.setState(store.getState()));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        why is this still false?
        {
          String(!!this.state.checked)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render((
  <App />
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Doesn't Work!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json (partly)

```
  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.3.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "superagent": "^2.3.0",
    "superagent-promise": "^1.1.0"
  },

  ...
```

Comment: [store#subscribe](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener) only triggers when a change is being made in the redux store e.g. after a dispatch. You should use `store.getState()` for the initial state creation as well in the constructor.

Comment: I am running `store.getState()` within `componentWillMount()` already. Shouldn't that suffice? What if I changed that to `componentDidMount()` instead?

Comment: No, because the callback you are passing in the `subscribe` method isn't called without dispatching an action.

Comment: @Christiaan Okay, so I understand that currently there is no `dispatch` so the value should not toggle. However, I do not understand why it doesn't display the `defaultState` which is `true`. I thought it should've JUST shown the `defaultState` and not changed.

Comment: @Christiaan Okay, I think your first comment has just made more sense for me. So, in essence, you are saying that unless the `dispatch` happens... Even the initial state creation won't happen. So, when the variable is accessed, it ends up being false. However, when `store.getState()` happens in the constructor, it will cause the store to be created and as a result the `defaultState` will take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-thunks-forked-yt47e?file=/index.js) demonstrating the order of procedure and the current redux state.

As you can see, the Redux state is actually up-to-date with the state you'd expect. However, the component state is never being set initially. This is because the callback you are passing to the [subscribe function](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener) is never called on mount.

You can solve this problem by setting the initial state to the redux state in the constructor:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = store.getState();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Much appreciated!